# Javascript Recursive function to build Tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, treeview, recursive-datastructures

Hi I am using `JavaScript` and `jQuery` as client side script. I am little bit new to `Recursive functions`. I have a JSON data as below and I have tried to make a tree structure using below JSON data by writing a recursive function but I am not able to build the tree structure.

```
var jsonData = { "$id": "45", "_children": [{ "$id": "46", "_children": [{ "$id": "47", "_children": [{ "$id": "48", "_children": [{ "$id": "49", "_children": null, "id": "Test1", "text": "Text1", "name": "name1", "parent": null, "root": { "$ref": "49" }, "depth": 0, "children": [] }], "id": "id1", "text": "text2", "name": "name2", "parent": null, "root": { "$ref": "48" }, "depth": 0, "children": [{ "$ref": "49" }] }], "id": "id3", "text": "text4", "name": "name4", "parent": null, "root": { "$ref": "47" }, "depth": 0, "children": [{ "$ref": "48" }] }, { "$id": "50", "_children": [{ "$id": "51", "_children": [{ "$id": "52", "_children": null, "id": "id6", "text": "text6", "name": "name6", "parent": null, "root": { "$ref": "52" }, "depth": 0, "children": [] }], "id": "id7", "text": "text7", "name": "name7", "parent": null, "root": { "$ref": "51" }, "depth": 0, "children": [{ "$ref": "52" }] }], "id": "id8", "text": "text8", "name": "name8", "parent": null, "root": { "$ref": "50" }, "depth": 0, "children": [{ "$ref": "51" }] }], "id": "id9", "text": "text9", "name": "name9", "parent": null, "root": { "$ref": "46" }, "depth": 0, "children": [{ "$ref": "47" }, { "$ref": "50" }] }, { "$id": "53", "_children": [{ "$id": "54", "_children": null, "id": "id10", "text": "text10", "name": "name10", "parent": null, "root": { "$ref": "54" }, "depth": 0, "children": [] }], "id": "id11", "text": "text11", "name": "name11", "parent": null, "root": { "$ref": "53" }, "depth": 0, "children": [{ "$ref": "54" }] }], "id": "0", "text": "0", "name": "", "parent": null, "root": { "$ref": "45" }, "depth": 0, "children": [{ "$ref": "46" }, { "$ref": "53" }] }
```

**Required Output:**

```
var treeNode = {
                    id: 101, // random
                    text: object.name,
                    icon: "fas fa-plus",
                    subNode: {
                        // id, text, icon and subNode of Children object
                        // recursive data,  So on.... 
                    }
                };
```

Can anyone suggest me or help me to write javascript or jQuery **`Recursive function`** based on above JSON data so I can build tree structure. I know I am asking about help because I do have less knowledge about recursive function.

Comment: Why downvote? please add comment

Answer (score 0):

If we abstract this a bit, it's pretty easy to write a general-purpose tree-mapping function.  Then we can supply two callback functions: one to find the child nodes of the input and one to build the output node based on the input and the mapped children.  Such a function turns out to be surprisingly simple:

```js
const mapTree = (getChildren, transformNode) => (tree) =>
  transformNode (
    tree, 
    (getChildren (tree) || []) .map (mapTree (getChildren, transformNode))
  )
```

For your data, `getChildren` is simply `(node) => node._children`

And the node transformation might be as simple as:

```js
const transformNode = (node, children) => 
  ({
    id: node.$id,         // or a randomizing call?
    text: node.name,
    icon: "fas fa-plus",  // is this really a fixed value?
    subNode: children
  })
```

Putting this together we get

```js
const mapTree = (getChildren, transformNode) => (tree) =>
  transformNode (
    tree, 
    (getChildren (tree) || []) .map (mapTree (getChildren, transformNode))
  )

const kids = (node) => node._children

const transformNode = (node, children) => 
  ({
    id: node.$id,
    text: node.name,
    icon: "fas fa-plus",    
    subNode: children
  })

const myTransform = mapTree (kids, transformNode)

const jsonData = { "$id": "45", "_children": [{ "$id": "46", "_children": [{ "$id": "47", "_children": [{ "$id": "48", "_children": [{ "$id": "49", "_children": null, "id": "Test1", "text": "Text1", "name": "name1", "parent": null, "root": { "$ref": "49" }, "depth": 0, "children": [] }], "id": "id1", "text": "text2", "name": "name2", "parent": null, "root": { "$ref": "48" }, "depth": 0, "children": [{ "$ref": "49" }] }], "id": "id3", "text": "text4", "name": "name4", "parent": null, "root": { "$ref": "47" }, "depth": 0, "children": [{ "$ref": "48" }] }, { "$id": "50", "_children": [{ "$id": "51", "_children": [{ "$id": "52", "_children": null, "id": "id6", "text": "text6", "name": "name6", "parent": null, "root": { "$ref": "52" }, "depth": 0, "children": [] }], "id": "id7", "text": "text7", "name": "name7", "parent": null, "root": { "$ref": "51" }, "depth": 0, "children": [{ "$ref": "52" }] }], "id": "id8", "text": "text8", "name": "name8", "parent": null, "root": { "$ref": "50" }, "depth": 0, "children": [{ "$ref": "51" }] }], "id": "id9", "text": "text9", "name": "name9", "parent": null, "root": { "$ref": "46" }, "depth": 0, "children": [{ "$ref": "47" }, { "$ref": "50" }] }, { "$id": "53", "_children": [{ "$id": "54", "_children": null, "id": "id10", "text": "text10", "name": "name10", "parent": null, "root": { "$ref": "54" }, "depth": 0, "children": [] }], "id": "id11", "text": "text11", "name": "name11", "parent": null, "root": { "$ref": "53" }, "depth": 0, "children": [{ "$ref": "54" }] }], "id": "0", "text": "0", "name": "", "parent": null, "root": { "$ref": "45" }, "depth": 0, "children": [{ "$ref": "46" }, { "$ref": "53" }] }

console .log (myTransform (jsonData))
```

This does something slightly different from your requested output.  You had written `subNode: { ... }`, but instead I'm returning an array of objects, `subNodes: [ ... ]`, as I don't make any real sense of a plain object here.

Also, this will yield an empty `subNodes` array if an input node has no children.  If you would rather not have the `subNodes` property, you could replace

```js
    subNode: children
```

with something like

```js
    ...(children .length ? {subNode: children} : {})
```

Obviously, you don't need the named helpers and could call `mapTree` with anonymous functions like this:

```js
const myTransform = mapTree (
  (node) => node._children, 
  (node, children) => 
    ({
      id: node.$id,
      text: node.name,
      icon: "fas fa-plus",    
      subNode: children
    })
)
```

This `mapTree` function was very easy to write, as I didn't have to think about any details of the output or input formats as I wrote it.  But perhaps that abstraction is not helpful to me, and I'm never going to use it except here.  If so, I can simply rework the abstract version by plugging the hard-coded callbacks directly.  With only a little manipulation, that will turn it into this version:

```js
const newTransform = (node) =>
  ({
    id: node.$id,
    text: node.name,
    icon: "fas fa-plus",    
    subNode: (node._children || []).map(newTransform)
  })

const jsonData = { "$id": "45", "_children": [{ "$id": "46", "_children": [{ "$id": "47", "_children": [{ "$id": "48", "_children": [{ "$id": "49", "_children": null, "id": "Test1", "text": "Text1", "name": "name1", "parent": null, "root": { "$ref": "49" }, "depth": 0, "children": [] }], "id": "id1", "text": "text2", "name": "name2", "parent": null, "root": { "$ref": "48" }, "depth": 0, "children": [{ "$ref": "49" }] }], "id": "id3", "text": "text4", "name": "name4", "parent": null, "root": { "$ref": "47" }, "depth": 0, "children": [{ "$ref": "48" }] }, { "$id": "50", "_children": [{ "$id": "51", "_children": [{ "$id": "52", "_children": null, "id": "id6", "text": "text6", "name": "name6", "parent": null, "root": { "$ref": "52" }, "depth": 0, "children": [] }], "id": "id7", "text": "text7", "name": "name7", "parent": null, "root": { "$ref": "51" }, "depth": 0, "children": [{ "$ref": "52" }] }], "id": "id8", "text": "text8", "name": "name8", "parent": null, "root": { "$ref": "50" }, "depth": 0, "children": [{ "$ref": "51" }] }], "id": "id9", "text": "text9", "name": "name9", "parent": null, "root": { "$ref": "46" }, "depth": 0, "children": [{ "$ref": "47" }, { "$ref": "50" }] }, { "$id": "53", "_children": [{ "$id": "54", "_children": null, "id": "id10", "text": "text10", "name": "name10", "parent": null, "root": { "$ref": "54" }, "depth": 0, "children": [] }], "id": "id11", "text": "text11", "name": "name11", "parent": null, "root": { "$ref": "53" }, "depth": 0, "children": [{ "$ref": "54" }] }], "id": "0", "text": "0", "name": "", "parent": null, "root": { "$ref": "45" }, "depth": 0, "children": [{ "$ref": "46" }, { "$ref": "53" }] }

console .log (newTransform (jsonData))
```

---

There's an important point here.  This generic function was much easier to write than if I'd tried to write something to convert your format directly.  While there is a danger in too-early abstraction, it also can offer significant benefits.  I might well choose to keep only that last version, but the generic abstraction *simplified* the development of it.

Answer (score 0):

It can be something like that, with using the json data model

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
  </body>
  <script>

var treeData={
   "Id":"10",
   "text":"Document Categories",
   "icon":"fas fa-plus",
   "subNode":
    [
      {
         "Id":"11",
         "text":"Pdf Documents",
         "icon":"fas fa-plus",
         "subNode":[
            {
               "Id":"31",
               "text":"Book Pdfs",
               "icon":"fas fa-plus",
                "subNode":[]
            },
            {
               "Id":"32",
               "text":"EPub",
               "icon":"fas fa-plus",
               "subNode":[
                  {
                     "Id":"20",
                     "text":"EBook Epubs1",
                     "icon":"fas fa-plus",
                     "subNode":[]
                  },
                  {
                     "Id":"30",
                     "text":"EBook Epubs2",
                     "icon":"fas fa-plus",
                     "subNode":[]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Id":"33",
         "text":"Text Documents",
         "icon":"fas fa-plus",
         "subNode":[
            {
               "Id":"32",
               "text":"Book Text",
               "icon":"fas fa-plus",
                "subNode":[]
            },
            {
               "Id":"35",
               "text":"Automatic Text",
               "icon":"fas fa-plus",
               "subNode":[]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
};

    var newTree = AddRecursive(null, treeData);
    var treeDiv = $('#myDiv');
    treeDiv.append(newTree);


function AddRecursive(tree, data) {
  if (tree == null) {
    tree = $('<ul/>');
    tree.attr('id', 'treeID');
  }

  var listU = $('<ul />');
  listU.addClass('ul class');

  var listItem = $('<li />');
  listItem.addClass('li class');
  listItem.attr('data-id', data.Id);

  var link = $('<a />');
  var i = $('<i/>').addClass('fa fa-folder');
  link.append(i);

  //link.addClass("linkClass");
  link.append(data.text);
  listItem.append(link);

  if (data.subNode.length > 0) {
    var span = $(' <span />');
    span.addClass('fa-chevron-down');
    link.append(span);
  }

  listU.append(listItem);
  tree.append(listU);

  for (i in data.subNode) {
    AddRecursive(listItem, data.subNode[i]);
  }
  return tree;
}



  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the question in this matter? Which is your goal? What have you done? Please write in detail to reveal your intentions in the question.